# Node JS File empty after read

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm Trying to log the location of tweets in a seperate JSON File for each Twitter ID i watch. The following code is called for each tweet and should create a new JSON File for each new ID and append the location of the current tweet:

```
console.log("@" + tweet.user.screen_name + " - " + tweet.user.name);
    
    timeStampNow = "[" + date.getDate() + ":" + date.getMonth() + ":" + date.getFullYear() + "-" + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds() + "]";
    
    console.log(timeStampNow + " " +  tweet.place.full_name);
    
    fs.exists(userData + "/" + tweet.user.id + ".json", function(exists) {

      //Is executed if file does not Exists
      if (!exists){
        console.log("Person Not Recognised. Adding to Folder");
        json = {};
        json.user = tweet.user;
        json.locations = [];
        
        fs.writeFile(userData + "/" + tweet.user.id + ".json", JSON.stringify(json), 'utf8', function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('complete'); 
        });
      }

      //Appends data to file
      fs.readFile(userData + "/" + tweet.user.id + ".json", function (err, data) {
        var readJSON = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(readJSON);

        locationJSON = {};
        locationJSON.time = timeStampNow;
        locationJSON.geo = tweet.geo;
        locationJSON.coordinates = tweet.coordinates;
        locationJSON.place = tweet.place;
        
        readJSON.locations.push(locationJSON);
        fs.writeFile(userData + "/" + tweet.user.id + ".json", JSON.stringify(readJSON), 'utf8', function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('complete'); 
        });
      });

    });
```

The First part of the Script functions without a problem, but the Part that should append the current location to the JSON File, sometimes makes files empty, resulting in an Error:

```
undefined
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\path\to\Program.js:44:29)
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:257:13)
```

Heres a example of how the JSON should look in the end:

```
{
    "user":{
        "id":"877id920012",
        "id_str":"id_str",
        "name":"name",
        "screen_name":"screen_name",
        "location":"location",
        "url":"url",
        "description":"description",
        "translator_type":"translator_type",
        "protected":"protected",
        "verified":"verified",
        "followers_count":"followers_count",
        "friends_count":"friends_count",
        "listed_count":"listed_count",
        "favourites_count":"favourites_count",
        "statuses_count":"statuses_count",
        "created_at":"created_at",
        "utc_offset":"utc_offset",
        "time_zone":"time_zone",
        "geo_enabled":"geo_enabled",
        "lang":"lang",
        "contributors_enabled":"contributors_enabled",
        "is_translator":"is_translator",
        "profile_background_color":"profile_background_color",
        "profile_background_image_url":"profile_background_image_url",
        "profile_background_image_url_https":"profile_background_image_url_https",
        "profile_background_tile":"profile_background_tile",
        "profile_link_color":"profile_link_color",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color":"profile_sidebar_border_color",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color":"profile_sidebar_fill_color",
        "profile_text_color":"profile_text_color",
        "profile_use_background_image":"profile_use_background_image",
        "profile_image_url":"profile_image_url",
        "profile_image_url_https":"profile_image_url_https",
        "profile_banner_url":"profile_banner_url",
        "default_profile":"default_profile",
        "default_profile_image":"default_profile_image",
        "following":"following",
        "follow_request_sent":"follow_request_sent",
        "notifications":"notifications"
    },
    "locations":[
        {
            "time":"time",
            "geo":"geo",
            "coordinates":"coordinates",
            "place":{
                "id": "id",
                "url": "url",
                "place_type": "place_type",
                "name": "name",
                "full_name": "full_name",
                "country_code": "country_code",
                "country": "country",
                "bounding_box": {
                     "type": "type",
                     "coordinates": "coordinates"
                },
                "attributes": {}
              }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fs.writeFile and read file are async operation. When you create file, it might also try to read the file which has not yet been created so you get undefined data. On the side note , check errors

```js
console.log("@" + tweet.user.screen_name + " - " + tweet.user.name);
    
    timeStampNow = "[" + date.getDate() + ":" + date.getMonth() + ":" + date.getFullYear() + "-" + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds() + "]";
    
    console.log(timeStampNow + " " +  tweet.place.full_name);
    
    fs.exists(userData + "/" + tweet.user.id + ".json", function(exists) {

      //Is executed if file does not Exists
      if (!exists){
        console.log("Person Not Recognised. Adding to Folder");
        json = {};
        json.user = tweet.user;
       
        locationJSON = {};
        locationJSON.time = timeStampNow;
        locationJSON.geo = tweet.geo;
        locationJSON.coordinates = tweet.coordinates;
        locationJSON.place = tweet.place;
        json.locations = [locationJSON];
        fs.writeFile(userData + "/" + tweet.user.id + ".json", JSON.stringify(json), 'utf8', function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('complete'); 
        });
      }else{
          fs.readFile(userData + "/" + tweet.user.id + ".json", function (err, data) {
        var readJSON = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(readJSON);

        locationJSON = {};
        locationJSON.time = timeStampNow;
        locationJSON.geo = tweet.geo;
        locationJSON.coordinates = tweet.coordinates;
        locationJSON.place = tweet.place;
        
        readJSON.locations.push(locationJSON);
        fs.writeFile(userData + "/" + tweet.user.id + ".json", JSON.stringify(readJSON), 'utf8', function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log('complete'); 
        });
      });
      
      }

      //Appends data to file
    

    });
```

, before perform any operation.